# How do specify which EditText should get focus on Activity starts and auto bring up keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to immediately highlight give focus to a particular edit box when the activity loads and bring up the softkeyboard.  how can I do this?  Also should there be anything in onStart()?

Answer (score 0):

You can call : requestFocus() on the View after you do findViewByID()

You can do that in onStart - I see now reason for it not to work.

Check here too :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the `getSystemService(...)`, one can obtain, in this case, the `Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE`, have a look at this code sample below for illustration:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(
                            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

imm.showSoftInput(edittext, 0, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout put `</requestFocus>` tag inside `EditText`.

In `onStart()` call

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should work.

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Abc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
```

But there have been some known issues of the keyboard not popping up. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2705).

You can also do this using Runnable:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 private Handler mHandler= new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // get text
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                text.requestFocus();                

            }
        });

        }
}
```